# How to display axes on an image with opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

Is there a way to show the row and column axes when displaying an image with cv2.imshow()?  I am using the python bindings for opencv3.0

Comment: I don't think so, try using photoshop, paint or gimp for the same , if possible

Comment: Thanks Hannes.  Matplotlib worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of.

However, since you are using Python you are not constrained to use the rudimentary plotting capabilities of OpenCV HighGUI.

Instead, you can use the much more competent [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) library (or any of the other available Python plotting libraries).

To plot an image, including a default axis you do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image, interpolation='none') # Plot the image, turn off interpolation
plt.show() # Show the image window
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question due to lack of info.

However you can use OpenCV's draw line function to draw a line from the example points (10,10) to (10,190), and another from (10,190) to (190,190)

On an example image that is 200X200 pixels in size, this will draw a line down the left hand side of the image, and a line along the bottom. You can then plot numbers or whatever you want along this line at increments of X-pixels.

Drawing text/numbers to an image is similar to drawing a line.

Once you have drawn the image, show with the usual image.imshow().

See OpenCV's drawing documentation here:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html

And an example to get you going can be found here:

http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/basic-drawing-examples.html#.VMj-bUesXuM

Hope this helps.